# how to make a cardview with a icon in the center with the text below it?

Tags: java, android, layout, android-cardview, screen-orientation

I want to make 2 rows and 3 columns card view with text below it (not inside the card view) and an image in the center of the card view.

[image]

> 

Comment: Its possible with several ways. Are you looking for static or dynamic UI?

Comment: I am looking for a static UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this**

> Just Copy and Paste your xml layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="dummy"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="dummy"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="dummy"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="dummy"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="dummy"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="dummy"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to use `GridLayout` and `CardView`. First we use RelativeLayout and make it gravity `horizontal_center` so that all our elements are in center.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
```

Then we use `GridLayout` to make grid like structure.

```
<GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:columnCount="3">
```

You can change row and colume according to your need. then we use `LinearLayout` to make `cardview` and `textView` vertically.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
```

then We just add our `Cardview` and `TextView` inside this layout like this:-

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardMaxElevation="12dp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Hello"
                />
```

Below is full code:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:columnCount="3"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardMaxElevation="12dp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Hello"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardMaxElevation="12dp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Hello"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardMaxElevation="12dp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Hello"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardMaxElevation="12dp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Hello"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardMaxElevation="12dp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Hello"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardMaxElevation="12dp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Hello"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to android, but realised a similar problem in one of my projects:

Personally, I always use the "Recycler View" component for and sort of Card View. For that you have to create two (or three) XML files (Recycler View itself and a single Card) and a custom RecyclerViewAdapter (For the e.g. onClick actions) (+ a Sort of fragment if you'd like to have a clickable card view, which would then open this specific card in e.g. a more detailed view. You however don't really have to do this. Therefore you can also work with two XML files).

First, the Card View itself: To have a Card View with an image "inside of it" and a text "below it", you have to simply style this in xml. To do that, you can work with "" inside of "</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>". Just style it as you'd like it to look.
You might be able to pull something off with a structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        
        <LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout >
                        
                        <ImageView />
                        
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView />

        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Then, the RecyclerView component:

This component is rather simple: You just have to put "<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView" in a position where you'd like it to be. Give it an ID and then you can start with the next part:

The RecyclerViewAdapter:

Create a class which implements "RecyclerView.Adapter" (sorry if I'm wrong with 'implements'. I'm fairly new to kotlin :)".

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(private val context: Context?, remindersIn: List<Reminder>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ReminderViewHolder>() {
    
    private val reminders: List<Reminder> = remindersIn
    private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ReminderViewHolder {

        val recyclerViewItem: View = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview_layout, parent, false)

        recyclerViewItem.setOnClickListener {
            v -> onClick(parent as RecyclerView, v, context)
        }

        return ReminderViewHolder(recyclerViewItem)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ReminderViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val reminder: Reminder = reminders[position]

        holder.descriptionView.text = reminder.description
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return reminders.size
    }

    private fun onClick(recyclerView: RecyclerView, itemView: View, context: Context?) {
        val itemPos = recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(itemView)

        findNavController(itemView).navigate(RemindersFragmentDirections.actionRemindersToPopup(itemPos))
    }
}
```

(Additional note: If you're planning on using any form of onClick event I highly recommend the usage of "NavArgs". With NavArgs you can send information in form of parameters from a Fragment to another Fragment).

Last but not least there's the Fragment for the onClick element, if you're planning to implement it. This just works like a normal Fragment and fetches it's data via the NavArgs.

If you have any questions or any feedback to my answer, I'd love to hear that. I then will improve my answer.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap your CardView and your TextView in a Vertical LinearLayout. You can create a layout file and reuse it as per your requirements